# Hyphenated company name in Java packages

Tags: java, naming-conventions, package

Say you're working on the core module of the `foo` project for BarBaz Incorporated. Your code fragment might look like this:

```
package com.barbaz.foo.core;

import com.barbaz.foo.util;
```

What would the convention be if your company's website was not `barbaz.com`, but instead `bar-baz.com`?

Comment: So it turns out there is a small amount of Java happening on the other side of the building, although I didn't find this out until after I asked the question. Their approach, following this example's format, was `com.bb.foo.*;` which makes sense considering all the legacy systems are bbs, bbw, bbj, bbl and what not. Thanks for the input though!

Comment: I reopened this because after thinking about it, it isn't a duplicate of the other question. That question is what do you do about a space whereas this question is what do you do about a hyphen.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

The SUN-era [Java Language Specification](https://web.archive.org/web/20090201061750/http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/packages.html) gives a suggested convention:

> If the domain name contains a hyphen, or any other special character not allowed in an [identifier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8) (§3.8), convert it into an underscore.

But it's just a suggestion...

Comment: That's interesting, considering how most Java suggestions recommend against the use of underscores in most identifiers.

Comment: According to this, it's a REQUIREMENT, not a suggestion (JSR)?  Isn't that correct?
https://blog.eisele.net/2010/09/hyphen-ussage-in-package-names.html

Answer (score 70):

I just looked through my browser's history, and in the last 2 months I haven't visited a single domain with a hyphen. So the convention is to rename the company.

Alternatively, leave out the hyphen, because BazBaz won't ever include Baz=Baz's code in their own.

Comment: I think the board of directors will take issue with this approach, but I LOL'd as well!

Comment: Apparently, only the person who asked the question can accept an answer. Unfortunately...

Comment: "...rename the company" - not very helpful.

Comment: LOL. Leading to another stackoverflow question "what is the eclipse shortcut key to rename my company. ALT+Shift+R is not working"

Answer (score 18):

I would personally just remove the hyphen. You *could* change it into an underscore, but that would look pretty ugly.

It's highly unlikely it's *really* going to clash with another company with the same name minus the hyphens. Even if both companies are tech companies, both using Java, what are the chances that anyone's going to be using code created by both of them in the same codebase?

To be honest, I wish that Java hadn't gone down this path in terms of conventions. I wonder how many directories called "com" or "org" exist with a single member - a subdirectory with a more meaningful name.

Comment: So I ran into this the other day again (I'm actually not at the same place anymore) and I stumbled across an [Oracle tutorial with a handy chart at the bottom](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html). According to the way back machine, it's [been around since late 2011](http://web.archive.org/web/20111117054510/http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html), a year after this question. The recommendations at the bottom sure do make me wonder!

Comment: @corsiKa: Ick. Looks horribly ugly to me! I can't remember the last time I saw an underscore in a package name, to be honest...

Comment: I work at a company that has a | character in it's official legal entity name. Literal hell.

Comment: My high school still has it in their domain name after more than 20 years. The irony is that its full name does not have the hyphen!

Comment: My packages just have the main domain name sel2in.translate ... or s2n.translate i mean unless there is a company called s2n who also do what i do...leave out the com

Answer (score 10):

Just drop the hyphen.  The package name doesn't need to match the website name at all.  It is more important that there's consistency among packages produced by the company so they all use the same base package name.

Comment: It is also used to avoid namespace collisions in libraries.  If barbaz.com created a product using a library from bar-baz.com (who dropped their hyphen) there would possibly be conflicts.  In practice this is so unlikely as to be laughable.

Comment: If barbaz.com and bar-baz.com were both producing libraries, one of them would be suing the other.

Comment: Upon further consideration, I had to give the checkbox to Steve's suggestion. Check out the links in my comment on Jon Skeet's answer for why.

Comment: I cannot complain about that.

Answer (score 4):

I work on lots of government stuff and we typically use the underscore so bar_baz.