# Error importing java package due to special character in domain

Tags: java

I am coding to download some data from google apps domain greenleaf-uae.com, but when i enter the command

```
import com.google.gdata.data.greenleaf-uae.generic.GenericEntry;
```

it gives me an error that ";" is expected and points to the "-" character. Is there something I am doing wrong.

How can I solve this.

Regards,
Arjun

Comment: Use underscores `_` (ref. [package naming](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html))

Comment: does not work, now i get more errors that package does not exist

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hyphenated company name in Java packages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678520/hyphenated-company-name-in-java-packages)

Answer (score 1):

From Oracle Docs:

In some cases, the internet domain name may not be a valid package name. This can occur if the domain name contains a hyphen or other special character, if the package name begins with a digit or other character that is illegal to use as the beginning of a Java name, or if the package name contains a reserved Java keyword, such as "int". In this event, the suggested convention is to add an underscore.

See the examples here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html

Answer (score 1):

A hyphen is not a valid character for a package name. From [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html) about naming packages:

> In some cases, the internet domain name may not be a valid package name. This can occur if the domain name contains a hyphen or other special character, if the package name begins with a digit or other character that is illegal to use as the beginning of a Java name, or if the package name contains a reserved Java keyword, such as "int". In this event, the suggested convention is to add an **underscore**.

So name you package as `com.google.gdata.data.greenleaf_uae.generic.GenericEntry`, and make sure to change the corresponding folder name from `greenleaf-uae` to `greenleaf_uae` as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create your own package names, just use a different character to make it valid. If you want to use an existing API you need to double check: as - is invalid there is most likely no API out there which uses that package.

Is this an external API shipped in a JAR file? Then open it and check it out. Based on the naming conventions I suspect you want to use the gdata-java-client, it has a package named:

```
import com.google.gdata.data.appsforyourdomain.generic;
```